# Valid induction?

Tags: matrices, induction, determinant

The problem was presented like this:

$A_{2n} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & \cdots & 0 & b\\ 
0 & a & \cdots & b & 0\\ 
 &  & \cdots &  & \\ 
0 & b & \cdots & a & 0\\ 
b & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a
\end{bmatrix} 
n \in N, A_{0} = 1
$

Show that $detA_{2n} = (a^{2} - b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2n-2}$

I tried to use induction for this case:

Base case:

$n=1$: $detA_{2n} = \begin{vmatrix}a & b\\ b & a\end{vmatrix} = a^{2}-b^{2} = a^{2}-b^{2} \cdot detA_{2n-2} = a^{2}-b^{2} \cdot detA_{0} = a^{2}-b^{2} \cdot 1 = a^{2}-b^{2} $

Hypothesis:

$ detA_{2n} = (a^{2} - b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2n-2} \Rightarrow detA_{2(n+1)} = (a^{2} - b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2(n+1)-2} $

$detA_{2(n+1)} = (a^{2} - b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2(n+1)-2} \Leftrightarrow detA_{2n+2} = (a^{2} - b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2n+2-2} \Leftrightarrow detA_{2n+2} = (a^{2} - b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2n} \Leftrightarrow detA_{2n} = (a^{2} - b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2n-2}$

This feels circular, is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the argument you gave is circular (not valid).

The issue is that you are not attending to the way the variable $n$ is [quantified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)); in other words, which values of $n$ you are talking about and when. The deduction $\operatorname{det}A_{2n}=(a^2-b^2)\cdot \operatorname{det}A_{2n-2}\Rightarrow \operatorname{det} A_{2(n+1)} = (a^2-b^2)\cdot \operatorname{det} A_{2(n+1)-2}$ is only a valid deduction if the first formula has already been established *for all $n$*. Because then you can substitute any value for $n$ and the conclusion will hold (in particular, you could substitute $n+1$, as you did, and deduce the second formula). So the logic you propose is indeed circular because you are using as the induction hypothesis the statement that "$\operatorname{det}A_{2n}=(a^2-b^2)\cdot \operatorname{det}A_{2n-2}$ holds for all values of $n$," which is the desired conclusion, not something that you can validly suppose and deduce things from.

The way an induction proof works is that the induction hypothesis only supposes that the formula holds *up to a certain value of $n$*, and you treat higher values of $n$ as an open question. So you cannot just hop from $\operatorname{det}A_{2n}=(a^2-b^2)\cdot \operatorname{det}A_{2n-2}$ to $\operatorname{det} A_{2(n+1)} = (a^2-b^2)\cdot \operatorname{det} A_{2(n+1)-2}$. The whole work of the argument is to see if you can suppose the first formula *only holds for a certain value of $n$* and validly deduce that the second formula holds for that value of $n$, or, equivalently, that the first formula *also* holds for *the next* value of $n$. This is how an induction proof does its work. You need to establish two things: (1) the proposition is true for a certain, specific ("base case") value of $n$; (2) IF the proposition is true for *any particular* value of $n$, then it is also true for *the following* value of $n$ ("the induction step"). If you establish these two things, then the fact that it is true in the base case means, because of the induction step, that it is also true in the case after the base case, and then, again because of the induction step, it is also true in the case after that, and so on.

I stress this to call your attention to the importance throughout the process of paying attention to which values of $n$ you are talking about. Your thinking will become much clearer if you avoid ever writing down a formula like $\operatorname{det} A_{2n} = (a^2-b^2)\cdot \operatorname{det} A_{2n-2}$ without specifying something about which values of $n$ you are talking about. You could write something like:

"By the induction hypothesis, we can suppose that $\operatorname{det} A_{2n} = (a^2-b^2)\cdot \operatorname{det} A_{2n-2}$ for a certain number $n$. The goal is to prove that the analogous formula holds for $n+1$."

The point is that you're only assuming the formula holds for one value of $n$, not for all, so you can't just immediately substitute $n+1$ for $n$. The following is more care than most people take, but I offer it in case it helps clarify your understanding of the induction process. You could also write,

"By the induction hypothesis, we can suppose that $\operatorname{det} A_{2n} = (a^2-b^2)\cdot \operatorname{det} A_{2n-2}$ holds when $n$ equals a specific number $N$, and our goal is to prove that it also holds when $n=N+1$."

Comment: Adding:

$detA_{2n} = a \cdot detA_{2n}(1|1) - b \cdot detA_{2n}(1|2n) = (a^{2}-b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2n-2}$, 
$detA_{2n+2} = a \cdot detA_{2n+2}(1|1) - b \cdot detA_{2n+2}(1|2n) = (a^{2}-b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2n+2-2} \Leftrightarrow detA_{2n+2} = (a^{2}-b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2n} \Leftrightarrow detA_{2n} = (a^{2}-b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2n-2}$

Makes it less circular?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the notation $A_{2n}(1\mid 1)$ etc., but, as far as I can tell, no, this does not make it any less circular. The problem is that you are substituting $n+1$ for $n$ in a formula that can only be assumed to hold up to a certain point. This is invalid because you can only make this substitution if you *already know* the formula holds with $n+1$ in the place of $n$, but this is what you are trying to prove. (I added more to the answer in hopes of clarifying the root conceptual issue, please read!)

Comment: @diogomgf Does A(m|n) denote the matrix obtained from eliminating the m-th row and n-th column of matrix A?

Comment: @Divide1918 yes it does

Comment: Thanks for the notational clarification. The previous comment stands. Manipulations of the form $det A_{2n} = a\cdot det A_{2n}(1|1) - b\cdot det A_{2n}(1|2n)$ will indeed be useful for a correct solution. But the key to avoiding circularity is to only apply the induction hypothesis for a value of $n$ lower than the one for which you're trying to prove the formula.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith I'm not sure I understood that reasoning, as I'm trying to prove for all $n \in N$...

Comment: I think you are missing a key point about how induction proofs work, about when and for which values of $n$ you are allowed to suppose the induction hypothesis. This answer is intended to clarify this key point, but if you don't find clarity in it, then I suggest the following exercise: study some basic induction proofs from the point of view of, "why should I believe this? Aren't they *all* circular???"

Comment: @diogomgf In any case, per the comment discussion on Divide1918's answer, in the actual case at hand, I think an induction proof would be a very unnatural approach. I think we were all focused on induction because the statement to be proven looks a lot like something that could be a *step* in an induction proof for *something else*. But to actually *prove* it, it makes much more sense just to try to do it directly. Nothing that $det A_{2n} = a\cdot det A_{2n}(1|1) - b \cdot det A_{2n}(1|2n)$ is actually half the way there.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith you're probably right...

Comment: Erratum: in my previous comment, "Nothing that..." was supposed to be "Noting that..."

Answer (score 0):

$$A_{2(n+1)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & \cdots & 0 & b\\ 
0 & a & \cdots & b & 0\\ 
 &  & \cdots &  & \\ 
0 & b & \cdots & a & 0\\ 
b & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a
\end{bmatrix}.$$

We will proceed using the appropriate cofactor matrices. First, expand along the first row, note that we have to negate the $(1,2n+2)$-th entry b since $2n+3$ is odd:

$$\det(A_{2(n+1)})=a \det\begin{bmatrix}
 a & \cdots & b & 0\\ 
 &  & \cdots &  & \\ 
 b & \cdots & a & 0\\ 
 0 & \cdots & 0 & a
\end{bmatrix}-b\det\begin{bmatrix}
0 & a & \cdots & b \\ 
 &  & \cdots &  & \\ 
0 & b & \cdots & a \\ 
b & 0 & \cdots & 0 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Here the cofactor matrices are of size (2n+1) by (2n+1). Now we expand the first resulting cofactor matrix along the last row and the second cofactor matrix along the first column. By the same logic as before, we don't have to negate anything in this case:

$$\det(A_{2(n+1)})=a^2\det(A_{2n})-b^2\det(A_{2n})=(a^2-b^2)\det(A_{2n}).$$

Hence we have finished the second part of the induction. Combine it with the base case check to complete the proof.

Comment: This problem I'm trying to solve comes before co-factor matrices in the book, so I'm not suppose to solve it using them...

Is this also a valid induction method?:
$detA_{2n} = a \cdot detA_{2n}(1|1) - b \cdot detA_{2n}(1|2n) = (a^{2}-b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2n-2}$,
$detA_{2n+2} = a \cdot detA_{2n+2}(1|1) - b \cdot detA_{2n+2}(1|2n) = (a^{2}-b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2n+2-2} \Leftrightarrow detA_{2n+2} = (a^{2}-b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2n} \Leftrightarrow detA_{2n} = (a^{2}-b^{2}) \cdot detA_{2n-2}$

Comment: The question was about the validity of the OP's proof, not a request for a valid induction proof.

Comment: Okay how would you normally evaluate the determinant of a large square matrix (say 6 by 6)?

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith The original question is about validity, which is already debunked by another user in another answer. In the comment of their answer, the OP of the question asked how could they write a valid proof, and I attempted to answer that question with this answer

Comment: Good to know. That said, if you are responding to a comment, you should do so as a comment in the same thread. An answer should directly respond to the OP.

Comment: @Divide1918 the book assumes its cumbersome to use the methods presented so far for large square matrices, and says that later on there will be other methods shown.

Comment: @BenBlum While I was asking for validity for the induction I presented, I would appreciate any corrections in case it was not valid (wich you pointed out it)...

Comment: I confess that I generally find it frustrating when OP's ask a focused question about their own thinking and answerers change the subject to *their* thinking. That said, perhaps my harsh reaction in this case was unfair. I made some trivial formatting edits just to make the software allow me to undo my downvote. :)

Comment: @diogomgf Your attempt in the comments here still fall into the trap of circular reasoning . Also I just realized my answer gives a direct proof instead of an induction proof.

Comment: @Divide1918 its usefull nonetheless.

Comment: Tbh, I think a direct proof is much more natural than an induction proof here. The statement to be proven would be *used* as an induction step in a proof that $\operatorname{det}A_{2n} = (a^2-b^2)^n$, that's made all of us think about induction; but it seems very unnatural to me to actually try to *prove* it by induction.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith True. I'm kind of stuck trying to come up with an inductive proof for this.